# Android: Job Scheduler for planner

Tags: java, android

I found out about Job Scheluder but I can't understand for what I can use it.

Is it suit to create planner, for example?
I want to launch notification in a month in setted day and time.

Is Job Scheluder good solution for that or I should choose something else? I want to find a good lib for this task.

Comment: `JobScheduler` is unsuitable for that, as you cannot arrange to get control at any specific time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. JobScheduler is for short term background tasks like when you want to download a file in the near future and want the system to find an ideal time for you. E.g. you want to download a big update file and want the device to be plugged in and have wifi rather then when the user is low on battery and wouldn't want to loose the last bits of energy for some file.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdINLG5QrJc explains
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html are the options you have to specify when you want your job to execute.

When you want to launch notifications at certain times look for `AlarmManager` http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html